# Does any House in Westeros suffer a worse fate than this House?

Tags: game-of-thrones, a-song-of-ice-and-fire

So (spoilers for all published ASOIAF books,)

> House Stark arguably suffers one of the worst fates of Westeros. Lord Eddard Stark is dead, so is his overlord Robert Baratheon; his wife and eldest son are slaughtered in the Red Wedding; all four of his remaining trueborn children are missing; his bastard son is presumably dead at the hands of his own men; the Starks have no viable heirs unless Bran or Rickon ever surface; Lord Stark's ancestral sword Ice was destroyed; his home burned to the ground; nearly all of his household were murdered.

The question is, does any House suffer a worse fate than this? The slaughter of Elia, Rhaenys and Aegon, and Daenerys and Viserys' subsequent exile are pretty nasty, but Daenerys is hardly complaining with a huge army and three dragons behind her. I'm not considering the Reynes and the Tarbecks - nasty as their extermination was - because there are no surviving members.

Comment: Well, considering your user name is "Leo King" at the moment, House Mufasa took it pretty bad at some point. But they managed to get back on their feet! ;-)

Comment: Huh, a Lion King pun, haven't heard that one before ;). Props for humour though, sometimes SE forgets how to have fun!

Comment: Four out of five Stark kids are alive, AFAIK. Plus, none of them have had intercourse with each other. I think in Westerosi terms that puts them way ahead of the curve. On a more serious note: they still have heirs *and* redundancies. It seems like many less protagonistic houses have suffered worse.

Answer (score 6):

[House Hollard](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Hollard) arguably suffers a worse fate:

> Following the Defiance of Duskendale, almost the entire House was executed at King Aerys's command. The only surviving member, Ser Dontos, was later made King Joffrey's fool before being double-crossed and killed by Littlefinger.

Answer (score 4):

There is also the destruction of [House Reyne](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Reyne) after they rebelled against House Lannister, immortalized in the Song "[The Rains of Castamere](http://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/The_Rains_of_Castamere)" which plays an important part in the books and the show.

Comment: It gets played so much, Lady Olleana makes a joke about it.  Miss that ol' lady

Answer (score 3):

House Targaryen has been suffering worse fates for centuries.

> The Dance of the Dragons. Baelor the Blessed. Aegon the Unworthy and the Blackfyre rebellions. Aerion Brightfire, the death of Baelor Breakspear and other events leading up to the succession of Aegon the Unlikely, the fourth son of a fourth son. The tragedy at Summerhall. Robert's rebellion and the deaths of Aerys, Rhaegar, Rhaenys and (arguably) Aegon.